# Date & Time Field for Google Community Connector not working as I want it to

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, looker-studio

I'm trying to develop a Google Community Connector for Looker studio and I'm fetching data from an API, one of the fields that I want to retrieve is a date&time value an the API gives me the date&time with the following format : "2023-02-22T19:26:44Z".

Since I do need to get the date and time I defined the field like this:

```
  fields
    .newDimension()
    .setId('timestamp')
    .setName('Date')
    .setType(types.YEAR_MONTH_DAY_SECOND);
```

I read the documentation for Google Field Types and the format for the YEAR_MONTH_SECOND type is the following: "YYYYMMDDHHmmss" e.g. 20170317023017. So I have a function that modifies the value retrieved form the api that looks like this:

*Link to documentation that I mention: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/data-studio/field-type

```
function yyyymmddhhmmss(date) {
  var MM = date.getMonth() + 1; // getMonth() is zero-based
  var dd = date.getDate();
  var hh = date.getHours();
  var mm = date.getMinutes();
  var ss = date.getSeconds();

  return [date.getFullYear(),
          (MM>9 ? '' : '0') + MM,
          (dd>9 ? '' : '0') + dd,
          (hh>9 ? '' : '0') + hh,
          (mm>9 ? '' : '0') + mm,
          (ss>9 ? '' : '0') + ss
         ].join('');
};
```

Before I call this function I convert the value retrieved from the API with this line of code:

```
var date = new Date(value);
```

Then I call the function yyyymmddhhmmss to format my date & time to be compatible with the YEAR_MONH_DAY_SECOND type. Everything apparently works fine, but when I want to use the field on Looker Studio for a filter or for a graph I only get null values. Am I missing something or has anyone had the same issue?

Comment: Hello Daniel I also faced this problem do you managed to solve it on your own?

Comment: could you change type of field type in connector field settings from text to date & time? I have tried for hours and it still does not allow me to change this saying that data format is wrong...

Comment: Try this replace:
`dateTimeString.replace(/-|T|Z|:/g, '');`

I was getting the same error but found that it was some additional characters/numbers that I wasn't noticing. Once I resolved it recognised the date. 

For debugging I output the date as string to an additional dimension (sanity check).